# Creating Java echo sound effect

Tags: java, audio, javasound

So I am trying to manipulate a sound file in java by breaking it up into samples and storing those samples in an array.  I then loop through the array changing each sample.  I realize that there is already an echo filter in java but I need to design my own by having the sound repeated at various intervals throughout the sound clip with diminishing volume.  I currently have a method that controls the volume but am stumped when it comes to getting the sound to repeat starting at a particular delay over the current sound file.  This is what I have so far:

```
public void echoEffect(int delay){
   SoundSample[] sampleArray = this.getSamples(); // get array

   SoundSample sample = null;                     // current sample obj
   int value = 0;                                 // value at sample

 // loop through SoundSample objects
 for(int i = 0, index = 0; index < sampleArray.length; i++,index++)
 {
  sample = sampleArray[index];    // get current obj
  value = sample.getValue();      // get the value
  sample.setValue(value*2);       // set the value
 }
}
```

What I believe I need to do is change the method from void to Sound and return the the delayed sound file.  Possibly returning something like value + value[i+delay]*(some fraction to decrease the sound)

New Update rather than post:

Anyway this is what I have so far I just can't seem to get the code to work properly and I know I'm close but I need the method to output an echo effect on a sound file.  Here is what I have at the current point:

```
public void echo(int delay){
   SoundSample[] sampleArray = this.getSamples();   // get array
   //Sound target = new Sound(sampleArray.length);

   SoundSample sampleDelay = null;
   SoundSample sample = null;                       // current sample obj

   int value = 0;                                   // value at sample
   int index = 0;
   double value2 = 0;
// loop through SoundSample objects
while (index < sampleArray.length)
 {
  sample = sampleArray[index]; // get current obj
  value = sample.getValue();     // get the value      
  sampleDelay = (sampleArray[delay-index]);
  value2 = (sampleDelay.getValue()*.6);
  sample.setValue(value + (int) value2);       // set the value
  index++;                                  // increment index
 }
}
```

Let me know what you guys think all this seems to do is shift the amplitude for some reason...
The problem with posting an SSCCE is that this is using some classes that are not regularly in java I believe and therefor I was just looking for someone to help with the logic.  I'm trying to loop through the samples of a sound file then set the value at the delay point to be the beginning of the sound  but fainter in volume.  IDK if I'm explaining this right but I was hoping this would be a simple fix.

Comment: Same question in Objective C. Answer in C-like pseudo-code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793310/how-to-add-echo-effect-on-audio-file-using-objective-c

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`sampleDelay = (sampleArray[delay-index]);`

you want

`sampleDelay = (sampleArray[index-delay]);`

Comment: When I do change this I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -3000 where the number is equal to the delay value.  And thanks for the help.

Comment: @adrv1400 Well, then don't do accesses to the array below 0! :)

Comment: Yeah, you can't echo something that isn't there :) You'll want to start echoing at somewhere greater than the amount you are going back by..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not the following?

```
sampleDelay = (sampleArray[index*delay]);
```

Comment: This will give more delay as index rises. Delay should be constat. I thing Patashu's answer is in the right direction.