# audio delay making it work

Tags: c, audio, delay, libsndfile

I am trying to implement a simple audio delay in C.
i previously made a test delay program which operated on a printed sinewave and worked effectively.
I tried incorporating my delay as the process in the SFProcess - libsndfile- replacing the sinewave inputs with my audio 'data' input.

I nearly have it but instead of a clean sample delay I am getting all sorts of glitching and distortion.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include </usr/local/include/sndfile.h>//libsamplerate libsamplerate
//#include </usr/local/include/samplerate.h>

#define BUFFER_LEN 1024 //defines buffer length
#define MAX_CHANNELS 2 //defines max channels 

static void process_data (double *data, double*circular,int count, int numchannels, int circular_pointer );

enum {DT_PROGNAME,ARG_INFILE,ARG_OUTFILE,ARG_NARGS, DT_VOL};

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])//Main
{
    static double data [BUFFER_LEN]; // the buffer that carries the samples

    double circular [44100] = {0}; // the circular buffer for the delay
    for (int i = 0; i < 44100; i++) { circular[i] = 0; }  // zero the circular buffer

    int circular_pointer = 0;          // where we currently are in the circular buffer

    //float myvolume; // the volume entered by the user as optional 3rd argument

    SNDFILE *infile, *outfile;
    SF_INFO sfinfo;

    int readcount;
    const char *infilename = NULL;
    const char  *outfilename = NULL;

    if(argc < ARG_NARGS) {
        printf("usage: %s infile outfile\n",argv[DT_PROGNAME]);
        return 1;
    }

    //if(argc > ARG_NARGS) {
    //  
    //  myvolume = argv[DT_VOL];
    //};
    infilename = argv[ARG_INFILE];
    outfilename = argv[ARG_OUTFILE];

    if (! (infile = sf_open (infilename, SFM_READ, &sfinfo)))

    {printf ("Not able to open input file %s.\n", infilename) ;
        puts (sf_strerror (NULL)) ;
        return  1 ;
    };

    if (! (outfile = sf_open (outfilename, SFM_WRITE, &sfinfo)))
    {   printf ("Not able to open output file %s.\n", outfilename) ;
        puts (sf_strerror (NULL)) ;
        return  1 ;
    } ;

    while ((readcount = sf_read_double (infile, data, BUFFER_LEN)))
    {   process_data (data, circular, readcount, sfinfo.channels,  circular_pointer) ;
        sf_write_double (outfile, data, readcount) ;
    };

    sf_close (infile) ;
    sf_close (outfile) ;

    printf("the sample rate is %d\n", sfinfo.samplerate);

    return 0;
}


static void process_data (double *data, double *circular, int count, int numchannels, int circular_pointer) {

    //int j,k;
    //float vol = 1;
    int playhead;
    int wraparound = 10000;

    float delay = 1000;  // delay time in samples

    for (int ind = 0; ind < BUFFER_LEN; ind++){

        circular_pointer = fmod(ind,wraparound);     // wrap around pointer
        circular[circular_pointer] = data[ind];


        playhead = fmod(ind-delay, wraparound);     // read the delayed signal

        data[ind] = circular[playhead];            // output delayed signal

        circular[ind] = data[ind];   // write the incoming signal
    };


    //volume
    /*for (j=0; j<numchannels; j++) {
        for (k=0; k<count; k++){ 
            data[k] = data[k]*-vol;*/

        //}printf ("the volume is %f", vol);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Consider what `playhead` would be when, for example, `ind` is 0.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code that are causing you to access out of your array bounds and to not read\write your circular buffer in the way intended.

I would suggest reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer to get a better understanding of circular buffers.

The main issues your code is suffering:

1. circular_pointer should be initialised to the delay amount (essentially the write head is starting at 0 so there is never any delay!)
2. playhead and circular_buffer are not updated between calls to process_data (circular_buffer is passed by value...)
3. playhead is reading from negative indices.  The correct playhead calculation is

   ```
   #define MAX_DELAY     44100
   playhead++;
   playhead = playhead%MAX_DELAY;
   ```
4. The second write to circular_buffer at the end of process_data is unnecessary and incorrect.

I would strongly suggest spending some time running your code in a debugger and closely watching what your playhead and circular_pointer are doing.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem is that you pass circular_pointer by value, not by reference. When you update it in the function, it's back to the same value next time you call the function.

I think you are on the right track, here, but if you want something that's structured a bit better, you might also want to checkout this answer:

[how to add echo effect on audio file using objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793310/how-to-add-echo-effect-on-audio-file-using-objective-c)

Answer (score -3):

delay in sample can be put as 100 ms would be sufficient

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with the distortions the OP is asking about. Besides, his code implies a delay of around 22 ms (1000 samples at 44100 Hz).

Comment: This question fails to address the OP's problem - and is clearly also wrong.